# Laravel 5 - how to filter collection until specific count of items found?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

Now I have such code:

```
return MyModel::all()->filter(function($value){
    return $value->attribute == 5;
})->slice(0, 6);
```

Value of `attribute` is loaded through accessor, so I can't just do `where('attribute', 5)` instead. Is there any standard way to optimize this, so filter will return only first 6 matched items?

Comment: Do you want to take only first 6 matched items ? where('attribute', 5) is not working?

Comment: @Muthu17 `attribute` is defined as `getAttributeAttribute` accessor, which is'nt portable to SQL syntax, so `where` here will not work (there is no `attribute` field in the database at all).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your return:

```
MyModel::all()->take(6)->filter.....
```

or try to use `->paginate(6);` at the end of your query

Comment: No, in this case I'll get less than 6 items if some of them are filtered.